# event fired on control added to the listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to know which event is fired when ListBoxItems are added to the ListBox. Please take a note that I don't want an event when data changes. I want the event when control is added.

I have refered to this answer where they say use CollectionChaged Event It fires when Collection changes. So I cannot use that as that fires before the controls are added to the VisualTree.

You might be thinking why I need that. I simply want to change the width of the listbox to the widest item's width. If you are interested more in what I am trying to achieve then please have a look at my code:

```
private void SomeEvent(object sender, ............... e)
{
    double greatestWidth = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(sidebar) - 1; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem li = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sidebar, i) as ListBoxItem;
        li.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(sidebar) - 1; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem li = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sidebar, i) as ListBoxItem;
        if (li.Width > greatestWidth)
        {
            greatestWidth = li.Width;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(sidebar) - 1; i++)
    {
        ListBoxItem li = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sidebar, i) as ListBoxItem;
        li.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
class ResizablePanel : StackPanel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size calculatedSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);

        foreach (ListBoxItem li in this.Children)
        {
            li.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        }

        double greatestWidth = 0;

        foreach (ListBoxItem li in this.Children)
        {
            if (li.Width > greatestWidth)
            {
                greatestWidth = li.Width;
            }
        }

        foreach (ListBoxItem li in this.Children)
        {
            li.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        }

        calculatedSize = new Size(greatestWidth, calculatedSize.Height);

        return calculatedSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you doing this with code though it couldbe done in Style if you will set HorizontalAlighnment Stretch

Comment: @ethicallogics yes, I am aware of that it could be achieved using styles. But I want to have something different. I want to change the width of all the items so that their remains same at the same time their width should be exactly equal to the width of the item who contains the text with most characters.

Comment: @Vishal to make the size as of the largest item is also possible without manually taking control. I assume your root problem is not what you are asking. could you post any screen show of your expectation? any ways you can listen for parent changed event of the desired control to know when a control is being added to listbox.

Comment: @pushpraj my root problem is actually what i have asked. parent changed event of which control should i listen for?? Can you show a demo for what i want withou taking control manually?

Comment: for that could you provide the example how you are adding the items to the list box (sidebar)? what I can see from code is that you are calculating the width of the largest item while keeping it stretched. As an alternative approach you can use a custom panel for the listbox and have full control over that.

Comment: @pushpraj I am adding the items from database to model to viewmodel an then to view. Can you show how can I create a custom panel and how will that calculate the width???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as discussed here is how you can take control over most of the sizing aspects

start by defining a new panel and override the method `MeasureOverride`

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class MyPanel : StackPanel
    {
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            Size calculatedSize = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
            foreach (ListBoxItem item in this.Children)
            {
                //your logic with each item
            }
            return calculatedSize;
        }
    }
}
```

MeasureOverride method will be invoked whenever any item is added or removed or a change in layout is required i.e. resizing the container.

`foreach (ListBoxItem item in this.Children)` is with assumption that you are going to use with ListBox only. You may change the same as desired.

then use this new panel as

```
<ListBox xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <l:MyPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

with this approach you can control the sizing much efficiently

read more on [FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

after looking at the sample here are the changes you need to do to get the desired

- set the `Margin="10,5,10,5"` to sidebar ListBox
- add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to sidebar ListBox
- remove `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` from ContentPresenter in metro.xaml line 35
- set `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />` metro.xaml line 51
- add `<Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />` at line 52

Comment: I have tried as you suggested. But still I get the same output which I got before asking this question. I mean creating a panel and overriding its Measure method and implementing the required code does not make any changes to the output.

Comment: do you wish to resize the listbox? as the current approach will resize only the items panel? could you post a working sample?

Comment: yes I would like to resize the listbox. I would upload a sample in a bit.

Comment: You can download it here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bQlhmY0ZNOF9GbW8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here are the Database Files : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bWUk3ZXBNQmNxdzQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ok now tell me what is the need? appreciated if you could post a screen shot as well? it seems like the view it bit complicated to be auto resized. need to re layout the same.

Comment: Click on Transactions. Now see the sidebar. Especially the Selected zitem's Width. It looks really bad.

Comment: My output should look like this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/rwLh20gp/

Comment: here is a workaround. remove `ItemsPanel` i.e. `ResizablePanel` from sidebar ListBox and set `<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />` in Metro.xaml line 51. see the result if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I want the width of the selectedItem equal to the width of the widest listItem in that list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59872/discussion-between-pushpraj-and-vishal).

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to Items CollectionChanged like

```
        public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)mylistbox.Items).CollectionChanged += myListBox_CollectionChanged;
    }

        private void myListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender,NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Plus here you will get the items directly instead of using VisualTreeHelper

Comment: If I understand this correctly this will give the items, whereas the OP is looking for the controls.

Comment: Which Control if you see in code he is getting ListBoxItem using VisualTree .ListBoxItem li = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sidebar, i) as ListBoxItem;